# splash screen not showing in android phonegap 1.9 after build

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, splash-screen

Im working on phonegap 1.9 , android, eclipse 4.2, jquerymobile i want to display splash screen.I have used this [article](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html). Its working fine in android simulator but when i build application using build.phonegap.com/apps/MyAppId/builds  and run it on ipad default splash screen appears here is my code ,i have placed icons and spalshscreen images in their respective folders

java activity code

```
 public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",5000);
         }
        }
```

javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var onDeviceReady = function() {    
        cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
            document.getElementById("devready").innerHTML = "";
        };

        function CheckDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }  

</script>  

  <body onload="CheckDeviceReady();" id="stage" class="theme">
<div id="devready" data-theme="b">Device not ready..</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap Build only your web assets. It doesn't build any native source code (MyPhoneGapActivity.java). You can find **.apk** file in Eclipse project **bin** folder

create config.xml file in www folder and put splash image in **"splash/android/"** folder and then build in phonegap site. for more details see https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

**www/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    version   = "1.0.0">
  <name>Sample</name>
  <description>
    Sample
  </description>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.0.0" />

  <!-- Icons -->
  <icon src="icon.png" />

  <icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
  <icon src="icons/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
  <icon src="icons/ios/icon_at_2x.png" width="114" height="114" />

  <icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />


  <!-- Splash Screens -->
  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />

  <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

  <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />

  <gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

</widget>
```

Comment: any suggestions what to do to make splashscreen

Comment: where to create splash/android

Comment: in your "www" web assets folder

Comment: hi, above code work for me. Basically config.xml (splashscreen) won't work on android emulator. It's only work on build.phonegap.com output .apk file.

Comment: in my code its working in emulator and android device but not in ipad

Comment: yes i have following folders
assets\www\icons\android\icon.png
assets\www\icons\ios\icon.png
assets\www\splash\android\ic_launcher.png
assets\www\splash\ios\ic_launcher.png
and also in root 
assets\www\ic_launcher.png

Comment: in config.xml  for icon <br> 
<icon src="icon.png" />

  <icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
  <icon src="icons/ios/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
  <icon src="icons/ios/icon_at_2x.png" width="114" height="114" />

  <icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />

Comment: in config.xml 
   <gap:splash src="ic_launcher.png" /> 
  <gap:splash src="splash/ios/ic_launcher.png" width="1024" height="768" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/ios/ic_launcher.png" width="768" height="1024" /> 
  <gap:splash src="splash/android/ic_launcher.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
  <gap:splash src="splash/android/ic_launcher.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

Comment: i only want to buil this application  for ipad only i dont know how to write code in objective C but im good in javascript thats why i used phonegap

Comment: Try, to give name for Ipad: 
splash/ios/Default.png,
splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png,
splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png,
splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png,

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is difficult to edit config.xml 
Now you can edit config.xml using a GUI tool download it from here
http://configap.com/